# Centralized database for multiple applications

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

I think I have a fairly straight forward design question.

Say I have 3 applications

```
App1
App2
App3
```

They all need to access common data, so I made a common database with a table called `Locations`

All three apps can update the information in the table, but I want an `IsEnabled` for each application so each application can have the functionality to enable/disable each `Location` row in the table.

I don't think I want to make a `bit` column in the table for every app to see if its enabled or not but I don't know? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a separate table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE ApplicationLocations
(
    ApplicationID INT,
    LocationID INT,
    IsEnabled BIT
);
```

Now instead of adding a column to the locations table for each application, you just add a row to this mapping table. You can also extend this to support other properties that may be specific to an application:location combination.

Comment: Thanks! Now to figure out why EF won't let me do a where clause through the navigation property.

Answer (score 1):

If it was me, I would create an abstraction layer between the database and these applications. This would eliminate having to refactor all of the applications each time a database change is made and also give you a variety of options for controlling access to the data.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this quite easily:

- create three separate `AppXEnabled BIT` columns - let each app set their own "enabled" flag
- create a "combined" computed column that makes sure at least one of the three flags is set

Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable
   (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, 
    ...(your columns here) .....,
    App1Enabled BIT, 
    App2Enabled BIT, 
    App3Enabled BIT)

ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
ADD AtLeastOneEnabled AS App1Enabled | App2Enabled | App3Enabled PERSISTED
```

Now, your rows will have the three separate `AppXEnabled` flags - and a combined flag `AtLeastOneEnabled` that will the `true (1)` when at least one of the flags is set, and will be `false (0)` when none of the three app flags is set.

This is a computed column, meaning it will always be up to date and updated by SQL Server as needed.

Comment: The issue with this is schema maintenance. Say we add App4 and App5, now we need to change the table structure and the computed column.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: yes, of course - it works fine as long as you have three, four apps - and that number isn't likely to increase quickly and significantly. On the other hand: the trouble you have to go through is a lot less than with your solution, as long as you do have a small number of apps.

Comment: I think we might have different definitions of "trouble" - I like to express these things relationally rather than as properties - having a column with data in the name doesn't feel right to me. Another problem with yours is if you want to add another property per app... there's three more columns, etc.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: agreed - if you need more than just this single "enabled" flag for each app, then no question - your approach is the way to go.